# Joins Great Grandparent Model - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm sure this is very simple but I cannot get it to work. I have the following associations.

```
model Category
  has_many :category_brands
end

model CategoryBrand
   has_many :category_models
   belongs_to :category
end

model CategoryModel
   has_many :products
   belongs_to :category_brand
end

model Product
   belongs_to :category_model
end
```

In theory, I want to query all D records that have an A record with the name equal to "x". So like this:

```
 @products = Product.joins(category_model: {category_brand: :category}).where("category.name like ?", "%Incline Motors%")
```

But I cannot get this to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Current Error:

```
G::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "category" LINE 1: ...es"."id" = "category_brands"."category_id" WHERE (category.n... ^ : SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "products" INNER JOIN "category_models" ON "category_models"."id" = "products"."category_model_id" INNER JOIN "category_brands" ON "category_brands"."id" = "category_models"."category_brand_id" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "category_brands"."category_id" WHERE (category.name like '%Incline Motors%')
```

Comment: What results are you getting?

Comment: @MichaelGorman I've updated my question with the error and the actual model names in my code. I tried the curly braces too.

Comment: The error message is saying the table `category` was never joined into the request. It wasn't, because the table is actually `categories`.  David Aldridge's answer should solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table name should be pluralised -- note the SQL statement text `INNER JOIN "categories"`

```
 @products = Product.joins(category_model: {category_brand: :category}).where("categories.name like ?", "%Incline Motors%")
```